# accepts_nested_attributes_for filter on listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it seems reject_if can be used to filter on saving, but what can I use to filter on listing? Let say I have a user that has many accounts, but on one page I only want to show checking accounts, so I want to filter the relationship. How would I do this? I was thinking I could create another relationship to use here, but in this case its a dynamic relationship (meaning its based on an external attributes value)

thanks
Joel

(ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5)

Answer (score 0):

I got this backwards in my original answer. You want a list of a single user's checking accounts not a list of users with checking accounts?

That's much easier. Assuming you have a User in a variable called @user.

```
@checking_accounts = Account.where(:user_id => @user.id, :account_type => 'checking')
```

or simply

```
@user.accounts.where(:account_type => 'checking')
```